# Adding more number of View and NSOpenGLView in NSWindow

Tags: cocoa, opengl, nsopenglview

I need to add more number of NSView along with more number of customised NSOpenGLView in a window and then wants to shuffle the array of views. If I set the base view setWantsLayer:YES initially, I can't draw the OpenGLView if I set setWantsLayer:NO, I can draw OpenGLView but the NSView are goes beyond the OpenGLView. Like,

In MyOpenGLView.m

```
myOpenGLView = [ [ MyOpenGLView alloc ] initWithFrame:frame_ colorBits:16 depthBits:16 fullscreen:FALSE ];
[self  addSubview: myOpenGLView];
```

Then I try to add one more view on window

```
 customView = [[CustomView alloc] initWithFrame:[self bounds]];
 [self  addSubview:customView];
```

Now my custom View goes beyond the myOpenGLView. How do I fix this?

**Edit**:

Screenshot of Problem

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you mean?

Comment: I am unable to add image , because I have no enough reputations. If u give ur mail_id, I will send you.  Thanks in advance

Comment: Upload the image using another site like imgur and embed it

Comment: I have added 3 screenshots in single image and the link is   http://imgur.com/8Y78xDt. First screenshot represents OpenGlView alone and the remaining two contains NSView along with openGLView. I am trying to create "Sketch" like app with 3D objects. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So to rephrase your question, you want the OpenGLView to go behind other NSView's?

Comment: Yes. Exactly, I want that only.